# Error while fitting my model after one batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am fitting my data to a CNN. When I use my own dataset, it immediately shows an error after the first batch is passed to the fitting function. This code works fine for another dataset.

The code is as follows:

```
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
    model.optimizer.lr = 0.0001
    epochs = 10
    number_pics_per_batch = 5
    steps = len(train_descriptions)//number_pics_per_bath
    for i in range(epochs):
        generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
        model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
```

**The error is as follows:**

```
This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
 12/441 [..............................] - ETA: 1:27 - loss: 5.7915
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-afd8541ef3c8> in <module>
      1 for i in range(epochs):
      2     generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
----> 3     model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   2221         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   2222         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 2223         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   2224 
   2225   @doc_controls.do_not_generate_docs
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:
UnknownError: Graph execution error:
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  KeyError: 'eb808f61-81d5-441b-9480-ddaa24746115.jpg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 271, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1004, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 830, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():
  File "<ipython-input-61-381145846d3a>", line 12, in data_generator
    photo = photos[key+'.jpg']
KeyError: eb808f61-81d5-441b-9480-ddaa24746115.jpg
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_12]]
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason model is fit in a loop with only the epochs changing?

Comment: Thats a good point. I reused an old code. I will probably code it from scratch again.

Comment: I also found out that there was a mismatch between the number of train_descriptions and train_features which could probably cause this.